# What does "Incorrect number of type parameters" mean?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
function format(date: Date, level: string, fnLabel: string, msgArgs: ?Array) : string {
         const l = (fnLabel === null || fnLabel === undefined) ? '' : ` ${fnLabel}`;
         return `${date.toISOString()} ${level}${l}: ${joinMsgArgs(msgArgs)}`;
     }
```

And I get the following message when using flow:

```
175:      function format(date: Date, level: string, fnLabel: string, msgArgs: ?Array) : string {
                                                                                ^^^^^ Incorrect number of type parameters (expected 1)
```

What does this "Incorrect number of type parameters (expected 1)" message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error was due to not specifying the elements of array, which can be of any type.  The following solved the issue:

```
function format(date: Date, level: string, fnLabel: string, msgArgs: ?Array<any>)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function format(date: Date, level: string, fnLabel: string, msgArgs: ?Array)
```

You're adding 4 parameters to the format function: date, level, fnLabel, and msgArgs. Format only takes 1.

Comment: But it's happy with 3 arguments.  This is the definition of `format`, so how does the error occur here.  I also used a different name for `format` and it still gives  the same error. If I change `?Array` to `?string` it seems to work.

Comment: ... discovered the issue, I need to use `?Array<any>`.